# Can I use "as an early lunch" instead of "for an early lunch"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Does the sentence "I made a pizza as an early lunch." sound good? I think that I want to rather emphasize that the meal was made to serve as an early lunch, and not that I ate it at an earlier time than the usual lunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As or for, both are fine

Using "as" suggests that lunch is the pizza.

Using "for" suggests that lunch will include the pizza

But really there is hardly any difference. I don't see a sense of "not that I ate an earlier time". I'd assume that in either case you had lunch early.